# Build em slave Jenkins com JDK não previamente instalado

Tags: jenkins

Eu tenho um servidor Jenkins que orquestra meu build. De modo geral, ele realiza builds mais leves, mas eu preciso do *slave* para fazer o build de projetos GWT pelo SSD. Eu tenho *alguma* liberdade com esse *slave*, mas ele é um recurso emprestado de outra empresa.

Por sinal, nessa máquina que a outra empresa cedeu gentilmente, existe um Jenkins servidor no qual se realiza o build do produto dessa outra empresa. E não gostaria de importunar com eventual mudança de JDK sem ter controle de que a mudança será completamente *sandboxed* para não afetar o produto alheio.

Opções de JDK de builds disponíveis:

[image: opções de JDK disponíveis, 7u65, 6u45, 8u25, 8u91]

Configurei o Jenkins para fazer o build com JDK8u91 conforme a imagem:

[image: opção JDK8u91 selecionada]

Obtendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Installing PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe
>   [JDK_8u91] $ PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u91 /L PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\install2115761959202298069log
>   ERROR: SEVERE ERROR occurs
>   org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe" (in directory "PATH\TO\SLAVE\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u91"): CreateProcess error=740, A operação solicitada requer elevação
>   at org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectVariableGetter.getBuildVariables(EnvInjectVariableGetter.java:91)
>     [... linhas omitidas por aparentarem serem irrelevantes ...]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "PATH/TO/SLAVE/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe" (in directory "PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u91"): CreateProcess error=740, A operação solicitada requer elevação
>   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>     [... linhas omitidas por aparentarem serem irrelevantes ...]
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, A operação solicitada requer elevação
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>     [... linhas omitidas por aparentarem serem irrelevantes ...]

Acessei o servidor *slave* e rodei a linha de comando de instalação manualmente no prompt com permissões de administrador:

```
PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u91 /L PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\install2115761959202298069log
```

Porém, ao tentar fazer o build novamente, obtive exatamente a mesma mensagem de erro. Como se o Jenkins não tivesse identificado a existência do JDK recém instalado.

Ao tentar selecionar JDK8u25, o Jenkins pensou que estava instalado porque não tentou rodar o instalador, mas na real está com uma inconsistência no sistema porque o executável não se encontra no lugar desejado:

> [projeto-gwt] $ OTHER\JENKINS\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u25\jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java -cp PATH/TO/SLAVE/maven31-agent.jar;PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MVN_311\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar;PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\MVN_311/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/MVN_311 PATH\TO\USER\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\3\893ffc3-1f519d29 PATH/TO/SLAVE/maven31-interceptor.jar PATH/TO/SLAVE/maven3-interceptor-commons.jar 51822
>   ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "OTHER\JENKINS\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u25\jdk1.8.0_25/bin/java" (in directory "PATH\TO\SLAVE\workspace\GeoSales_Portal\portal"): CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
>     [... linhas omitidas por aparentarem serem irrelevantes ...]

---

- Como fazer a instalação do JDK via Jenkins no *slave* sem precisar de acessos elevados?
- Ou então, como contornar essa situação, instalar de modo *sandboxed* o JDK e **conseguir indicar** ao Jenkins isso?

---

Sobre corrigir o projeto GWT para fazer o build ficar rápido... estamos trabalhando nisso. São 109 classes que tratam das requisições assíncronas do GWT, feitos passando `HashMap` e recebendo `List` ou `List<HashMap>` como resposta. Sim, foi feito *raw* originalmente. Mas o trabalho do legado é muito grande para corrigir, estamos trabalhando desde o ano passado entre uma customização e outra para diminuir o tempo que o GWT fica processando o oráculo tipando as coisas, ou usando classes específicas para o fim necessário.

Mas isso não é viável consertar no curto prazo...

Comment: O slave está rodando como serviço de Windows lá do outro lado? Talvez isso aqui dê uma luz (nao tento responder não tenho nenhuma maquina Windows aqui pra tentar replicar o problema, haha): https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-General-Discussions/Jenkins-execution-gt-The-requested-operation-requires-elevation/td-p/144347

Comment: @nunks.lol não é serviço, `jnlp` faz sentido? Esse nome me veio à cabeça

Comment: @nunks.lol, minha VPN não está funcionando. Segunda eu tento explorar essas opções

Comment: faz sentido, jnlp é extensao de Java Web Start, aqueles serviços em que você baixa um applet... Nesse link q colei uma das possiveis saidas é rodar o agent JNLP como serviço no Windows remoto.

Answer (score 3):

Ainda estou lutando para tentar solucionar de modo mais elegante. Considerei a [resposta do @nunks.lol](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252739/64969) elegante, pondo o serviço e tudo o mais, mas como o servidor é Windows eu simplesmente não consegui fazer muito.

Depois de cansar de resolver elegantemente, resolvi tentar opções na marra. Então, encontrei esse link aqui que fala sobre [configurar JDK no Jenkins](http://www.studytonight.com/jenkins/configuring-jdk-in-jenkins) e percebi um detalhe importante:

> JDK can also be installed by intimating Jenkins to do the task. The check box install automatically needs to be checked in this case.

Em tradução livre:

> JDK também pode ser instalada intimando o Jenkins para realizar a tarefa. O *check box* "*install automatically*" precisa estar checada neste caso

Bem, eu já havia conseguido instalar manualmente o JDK desejado. Então, e se eu desejasse simplesmente evitar a instalação automática?

Bem, executei a instalação manual:

```
PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u151/jdk.exe /s ADDLOCAL="ToolsFeature" REBOOT=ReallySuppress INSTALLDIR=PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u151 /L PATH\TO\SLAVE\tools\hudson.model.JDK\install2115761959202298069log
```

E, na configuração das JDKs do Jenkins, adicionei a JDK `JDK_8u151_SLAVE` com o *check* "*install automatically*" **desselecionado**. Ficou assim:

[image: Janela exibindo o JDK_8u151_SLAVE sem instalação automática]

Então, no build do *job* que necessitava usar o *slave*, selecionei para rodar com essa JDK:

[image: Configuração do job]

Com isso, o Jenkins não tentou instalar por cima do JDK instalado, usando o já instalado.

Answer (score 2):

Decidi registrar aqui uma resposta, a partir [deste Q&A](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/TestComplete-General-Discussions/Jenkins-execution-gt-The-requested-operation-requires-elevation/m-p/144445#M26827) e da [documentação](http://support.smartbear.com/testcomplete/docs/working-with/integration/jenkins/requirements-and-limitations.html) da ferramenta TestComplete, especificando configurações necessárias para execução em instalações Jenkins em Windows.

O que me fez chegar a tal artigo foi o cerne da mensagem de erro apresentada na pergunta:

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, A operação solicitada requer elevação

Em inglês, para futura referência cruzada:

> java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation.

Esse tipo de mensagem ocorre quando é necessário que o usuário executante tenha permissões de Administrador, ou ao menos permissões mais elevadas do que as de um usuário comum, e pelos comentários você parece estar utilizando slave via JNLP: modo em que o servidor remoto abre uma página do Jenkins master e baixa um applet de agente, útil para situações em que o master não pode abrir conexão diretamente. O agente JNLP deve acessado e executado manualmente uma vez na máquina remota e depois instalado como serviço para que o procedimento manual não seja mais necessário, conforme [documentação do modo slave JNLP](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-LaunchslaveagentviaJavaWebStart).

Assim, pela mensagem de erro apresentada, é grande a possibilidade de que seu agente slave não esteja sendo executado como serviço no Windows remoto, sem permissões de administrador.

O que me causa certo estranhamento é ele requerer elevação para executar uma JDK, algo que eu achava que poderia ser executado por qualquer usuário:

> ERROR: SEVERE ERROR occurs
>   org.jenkinsci.lib.envinject.EnvInjectException: java.io.IOException:
>   **Cannot run program**
>   **"PATH/TO/SLAVE/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_8u91/jdk.exe"** (in directory
>   "PATH\TO\SLAVE\hudson.model.JDK\JDK_8u91"): CreateProcess error=740, A
>   operação solicitada requer elevação at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.envinject.service.EnvInjectVariableGetter.getBuildVariables(EnvInjectVariableGetter.java:91)

Será que a JDK do slave é configurada para, ao subir, abrir portas de rede só acessíveis a usuários privilegiados? Isso explicaria mensagem de erro análoga em Linux, mas não sou particularmente versado nas características de segurança do Windows.

Em tempo, pode ser uma boa consultar a [documentação do Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingslaveagents) para verificar se algum outro modo de configuração de slave não lhe é mais vantajoso.

Outro link que pode ajudar (peço desculpas se for algo muito básico, como disse não conheço muito de Windows e não tenho máquina aqui para testar esse *setup*) é [este artigo sobre serviços Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson8/), explicando como registrar a execução de serviços, como vinculá-los a usuários específicos e como lhe conferir acesso interativo à interface de usuário. Caso seu build Jenkins necessite executar comandos na GUI, como interagir com mouse e teclado, talvez você precise habilitar essa última propriedade, e a mensagem de erro recebida pode decorrer dessa falta de permissão, como citado no link do início desta "resposta", na documentação do TestComplete.

Comment: Dia de testar a solução...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado hahah, boa sorte!

Comment: Não consegui colocar como serviço u.u Não soube usar o "sc" para fazer isso

Comment: Consegui de um jeito alternativo do qual eu não me orgulho, mas insistirei mais nessa sua solução ainda

Comment: Vou tentar insistir mais na opção dos serviços... Enquanto isso, rodar uma JDK instalada manualmente quebrou o galho: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252849/64969 ; isto é, até alguém sem querer selecionar a opção que instala o JDK automaticamente, que vai sobrescrever o que instalei manualmente =)

Comment: Legal! Eu não tinha atinado que essa execução tratava da instalação da JDK, aí realmente precisa ser admin. E se você der um nome e um caminho personalizados para a JDK que instalou manualmente, algo fora dos padrões utilizados pelo Jenkins, para evitar que uma instalação automática sobrescreva a coisa toda? Pelo link que você postou na sua resposta, parece que o Jenkins aceita qualquer coisa.

Answer (score -2):

[no dashboard aparecem deve ingressar nas configurações gerais de jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTKAj.png)

[image: ingressar das configurações globais]

[image: e se configura o jdk e o maven com os arquivos na pasta do sistema local do mesmo modo como se configuram as variáveis de ambiente só que dentro de jenkins]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não vi como isso pode contornar o problema de instalar a JDK na máquina do jenkins secundário por falta de permissão.